# Ubuntu freezes when I run "ps" or "top"

Tags: ubuntu, bash, bind

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Bind9 (not working, won't accept connections) (named-checkconf and named-checkzone both work)
- OpenVPN (community edition) (working correctly) (bridged mode)
- PHP5 & PHP5-gd
- Mysql5
- Standard setup ubuntu server
- Bash shell

### Problem

Any command that monitors or reports on running processes causes the shell to repairably freeze. This includes `top` and `ps`.

I don't really know where to start on this issue. Any clues would be helpful. Issue started after install bind9 `apt-get install bind9 dnsutils`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

process monitoring tools will still query nss (name resolution layer) to map user ids to names... so problem is likely in the resolver layer...

Comment: yeah, turns out once I got bind working, everything was good

Comment: fix your nsswitch.conf and nscd configs...